# Trouble when attempting to import a dat resource

Tags: import, dataset

I am trying to import the "Patient Medical Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19" dataset from the Wolfram Data Repository, but when I import, it shows me just 427036 results instead of the 692145 shown in the repository (https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Patient-Medical-Data-for-Novel-Coronavirus-COVID-19).

I am using the code

```
ResourceData["Patient Medical Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]
```

Can anyone explain to me why Mathematica doesn't import the whole dataset?

After evaluating the `ResourceData` expression, I get the message:

> GlobalDateInterval::shdw: Symbol DateInterval appears in multiple contexts {Global`, System`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

I get the message only from the first evaluation, if I re-evaluate, I do not see the message.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you only get an old datatset?

Try

```
covid19data =ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]
DeleteObject[covid19data]; (* otherwise no update *)
covid19data =ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"];
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work either. I always get the short dataset...

Comment: @Anto `ResourceData[
  "Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"][Max, \
#ConfirmedCases["LastDate"] &]` shows the date of the data. I get `DateObject[{2020, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.]`

Comment: In case it helps: using Ulrich Neumann's three lines I get 846 sets of data in the initial dataset and everything on the Wolfram data repository page seems to work exactly as expected. The data set is number 287.0.0 (37.8Mb).

Comment: @pudepied  Thanks, that's what I get too.

Comment: What about ```ResourceUpdate["Patient Medical Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]```. It tells you when you have already downloaded the most recent version.